# How to upgrade from aws_iam_policy_attachment to aws_iam_role_policy_attachment safely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

The resource [aws_iam_policy_attachment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_policy_attachment.html) has the following warning

> WARNING: The `aws_iam_policy_attachment` resource creates exclusive attachments of IAM policies. Across the entire AWS account, all of the users/roles/groups to which a single policy is attached must be declared by a single `aws_iam_policy_attachment` resource. This means that even any users/roles/groups that have the attached policy via any other mechanism (including other Terraform resources) will have that attached policy revoked by this resource. Consider `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`, `aws_iam_user_policy_attachment`, or `aws_iam_group_policy_attachment` instead. These resources do not enforce exclusive attachment of an IAM policy.

We changed some of our code from

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "logs" {
  name       = "${var.function_name}-logs"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.lambda.name]
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.logs[0].arn
}
```

to

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "logs" {
  name       = "${var.function_name}-logs"
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.logs[0].arn
}
```

The change above is simple but now terraform wants to remove the `aws_iam_policy_attachment` resource and add the `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`. Previously, when we applied the terraform for a module using a shared managed IAM resource, it detached the policy from 30 different IAM roles, forcing us to reattach them by finding and reapplying our terraform modules.

What is a safe strategy to use the less dangerous resource `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`?

Our current strategy

1. Recreate managed IAM policy as an inline policy and add to role
2. Remove the managed policy manually using AWS console

   - Possibly easier with this CLI command. It just seems in the console.

     ```
     aws iam detach-role-policy \
       --role-name my-role-name \
       --policy-arn arn:aws:iam:1234567890:role/logs
     ```
3. Remove the bad resource from the state

   - May not be necessary since it was removed in the previous step
   - `terraform state rm aws_iam_policy_attachment.logs`
4. Target apply the new attachment

   - `target apply -target aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.logs`
5. Sanity check

   - `terraform plan`
6. Remove the inline policy from the first step

Comment: Unnerving in what way? It will just remove the existing attachment which means you will have a potential blip in IAM permissions (which you'd have with your manual approach too). Due to the fact that this is racy you might also need to apply twice. If the attach runs before the detach then the IAM API will likely error on the attach (attaching the same policy multiple times), then the detach will run and then show you the error. A second apply will fix that for you because the policy is already detached.

Comment: Agree that there is really nothing unnerving about an instantaneous policy re-attachment.  Since I do not believe policy attachments have AWS IDs (for the purpose of API), you would be unable to do state manipulation to work around this either.

Comment: You can actually import the [`aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html) so that is an option if you don't want to have a brief blip on IAM permissions while you refactor this or there's another reason you want to avoid a potential intermittent failure before a retry fixes things. I'd personally just run the apply and if it fails double tap it as this is a one off migration when refactoring.

Comment: When we applied the terraform for a module using a shared managed IAM resource, it detached the policy from 30 different IAM roles, forcing us to reattach them by finding and reapplying our terraform modules. We've come up with a set of steps to do this safely in the future but wanted to reach out to see if it can be done in a safer way. Have you folks run into this as well?

Comment: The importation of `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` isn't the issue. The issue is the removal of the `aws_iam_policy_attachment` which causes detachment in other roles outside of the terraform module being applied.

Comment: Are you saying it detached it from things that the Terraform state file didn't think were attached when you destroyed it? Because I don't think that should happen. The delete method on the resource expands the list of users, roles and groups in the configuration/state file and then detaches from all of those. If the Terraform configuration and state file only contains a single role for the policy attachment, even if it's actually attached to multiple other things in other state files or outside of Terraform, then it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. It removed the managed policy from IAM roles that were not in my current terraform module's state. This resource has bit us before and that's why we've been migrating our resources to use the safer one. Now we just want to confirm steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### note on state manipulation

Whenever I am going to do state surgery, I change the state to be a local state. Do all my operations. Then run a plan to ensure my changes have caused no diffs. Then put the state back to your propper backend. This article explains how to do that:

https://medium.com/faun/cleaning-up-a-terraform-state-file-the-right-way-ab509f6e47f3

But at a minimum, at least do: `terraform state pull > backup.tfstate`

### state commands for your task

first, make terraform stop tracking the old way you did this
`terraform state rm aws_iam_policy_attachment.logs`

Then just do an import on the new associative resource:

`terraform import aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.logs lambda-role/arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:policy/policy-name`

per docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment

Do a `terraform plan` and you should see no diffs.

### conclusion

This allows you to not touch your actual AWS configuration. You wont end up deleting any roles or permissions for even a minute. It's safe and verifiable, if you backup your state ahead of time.

Comment: This is actually a good advertisement for Pulumi. With Pulumi you can do state manipulation as part of the resource declaration. You can do imports, moves, etc. All in the same code you define the resource in to begin with. No CLI commands needing to save you.

Comment: Thanks. We did end up solving it using this method. Much easier to 1) remove the bad resource from the state, 2) convert the resource in terraform from the bad to the good one and 3) import the existing policy as the good resource in the state.